# How can I pair all the elements of a vector using backtracking

Tags: c++, backtracking

I have a backtracking homework problem and I can only get 80/100 points, due to my inefficient program. The statement of the problem is the following:

> n natural numbers are given (n is even). The n numbers are paired and for each pair, you find the remainder of the division between the two elements of the pair and sum all remainders. Find the minimum value of this sum.
>
> 2<=n<=18 and all n natural numbers are <=1000
>
> Example:
>
> n=4 and the 4 numbers are: {6, 5, 3, 4}
>
> The result is 1. Minimum sum of the remainders is 1 because 6 is paired with 3 and 5 is paired with 4. So we have the pairs : {6, 3} and {5, 4}. 6%3 == 0 so the remainder of the first pair is 0. 5%4 == 1 so the remainder of the second pair is 1. 0+1=1 is the smallest possible sum. There is no other pairing of the elements that give a smaller remainder sum.

So what I've tried (since this is a backtracking problem) is to generate all possible pairs, find the remainder sum and choose the smallest one. But my solution is not efficient enough, it only gets 80/100 points. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int n, a[20], v[20], first[20], second[20], suma_min=INT_MAX;

bool solution() {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if (a[i] != -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void find_sum() {
    int i, curr_sum=0;
    for (i=1; i<=n/2; i++) {
        curr_sum = curr_sum + (first[i] % second[i]);
    }
    if (curr_sum < suma_min) {
        suma_min = curr_sum;
    }
}

void backtrack(int k,int stage) {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if (a[i] != -1) {
            if (stage == 1) {
                first[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = -1;
                if (solution()) {
                    find_sum();
                }
                else {
                    backtrack(k, stage+1);
                }
                a[i] = v[i];
            }
            else {
                second[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = -1;
                if (solution()) {
                    find_sum();
                }
                else {
                    backtrack(k+1, stage-1);
                }
                a[i] = v[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    cin >> n;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        cin >> v[i];
        a[i] = v[i];
    }
    backtrack(1,1);
    cout << suma_min;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to do this faster? Is there an algorithm that pairs all the elements of an array, 2 by 2? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be bugged. You can never have a solution at stage one, because you haven't picked the second number yet.

Comment: And in any case `if (solution())` can more efficiently be replaced with `if (k == n/2)` but only at stage 2.

Comment: And now I think about it, doesn't your solution have the problem that you will pick the same number twice? You should be generating permutations of your numbers (which as it happens is not something you'd normally do with backtracking).

Comment: For the sake of clarity of implementation (and probably efficiency too) I would forget this stage 1 stage 2 business. Just pick numbers, and at the end all the odd picks will be first numbers, and all the even picks will be second numbers (given that you are counting your arrays from one).

Comment: @john But how would that try all possible pairings? I know that this stage 1 & stage 2 method is confusing and I want to solve the problem in another way, but I can't think of any. I don't think I fully understood your method, I don't see how pairing odd/even will try all pairs. Could you elaborate a little?